# how to determine whether location service is available?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Now I am writing a project about Battery Management.However,I don't know how to get the

service information of the system,such as blue-tooth,location service...

How can I Know this?

Comment: Does this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/windowsphonetrainingcourse_devicecapabilities.aspx ? But be aware, that according to this [Feature Request](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2046237-battery-apis-for-level-and-usage) it is not (yet?) possible to access battery charge level and such.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API for the battery charge level in `Window Phone`. 
 If you just want to know if the phone is running on battery or plugged in then you can use `DeviceStatus.PowerSource`.

And that is all what you can.